# Non-transient non-serializable instance field in serializable class

Tags: java, serialization, findbugs

Consider the following code :

```
public class LIMSGrid extends ClientEventSource implements Focusable, FramingBlockWrapper {

  //cell that is curently in edit mode
  private CellCoord editingCell = null;

  //framing block info
  private FramingBlock framingBlock;   

}
```

Now `ClientEventSource` extends a class  that implements `Serializable` interface . The classes `CellCoord` and `FramingBlock` are POJOS with a bunch of getters and setters . FindBugs is complaining about the `editingCell` and `framingBlock` fields saying :

> This Serializable class defines a non-primitive instance field which
>   is neither transient, Serializable, or java.lang.Object, and does not
>   appear to implement the Externalizable interface or the readObject()
>   and writeObject() methods.  Objects of this class will not be
>   deserialized correctly if a non-Serializable object is stored in this
>   field.

Okay so everything is fine except how come it is saying that the instance fields are not "java.lang.Object" . This is totally misleading or I am missing some basics here ?

Comment: I think it's just something that slipped in FindBugs. Those 2 classes are `Object`s (obviously) and `Object` does not implement `Serializable`. It doesn't make any sense to me either. My suggestion: make those 2 classes serializable or transient and move on :D .

Comment: possible duplicate of [FindBugs - SE_BAD_FIELD rule, why it ignores java.lang.Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899753/findbugs-se-bad-field-rule-why-it-ignores-java-lang-object)

Comment: @MikkoMaunu not quite a duplicate but thanks for pointing to that answer. It is useful.

Comment: What should be done if we are getting above issue due to byte[] used in a Serialized class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess (but it's only a guess) is that FindBugs doesn't trigger this warning if you reference `java.lang.object` instances, because it considers that in this case, your class is a generic container, which can hold any kind of object (like a Collection).

In that case, it's the responsibility of the user of the class to make sure that the object stored in the container is serializable if he wants the container to be serializable. (just like an ArrayList is serializable if and only if you store serializable objects inside the list).

Answer (score 0):

You should make CellCoord and FramingBlock serializable to avoid that error. If you don't want to serialize them, you should set them as being transient.

Comment: I understand this part but my question is why is FindBUgs saying that those fileds are not objects ?

Answer (score -1):

The objects of the classes will not be deserialize correctly if there is any one of the object defined in the class extending the serializable will have non-primitive instance field which is neither transient, Serializable. because if any object of class want to save the its state , it won't be able to do so just because of one  non-primitive instance field which is neither transient, Serializable.